# Can one derive Planck's law by considering a more "natural" setting?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

I have been wondering about this for a while. I've recently become a bit dubious regarding the usual derivation cited in textbooks of Planck's law (and its inaccurate predecessor, the Rayleigh-Jeans law) of thermal radiation from a black body on the basis of a cavity radiator. In particular, it's not that I feel this derivation is wrong, but that it feels a bit disconnected from how we usually think about heat. We don't think of specially-designed cavities with tiny pinholes in them - our personal experience with radiated heat is from things like the hot Sun, a hot stove burner (though some of that, particularly if your hand is above it, is also convection), and the like. Moroever, the "black body" is not *defined* as a cavity but as an ideally "as black as possible" object that is black to every form of EM radiation. (A black hole is perhaps the closest thing to one in reality.)

Hence, what I'd be after is if there's a way to derive Planck's law that more directly comes at this from that intuitive, pre-existing background. What I've attempted so far on this is this. Suppose that an object is composed of a bunch of atoms, which each can have a different energy. It has been pre-heated to a uniform temperature, $T$. Then, if $E$ is the given energy, we can describe the probability *density* for an atom to have that energy by the Boltzmann factor, i.e.

$$f_E(E) := \frac{1}{Z} e^{-E/(k_B T)}$$

However, the trouble here is in figuring out how to translate that to a light spectrum. We can imagine that the object starts radiating off energy, but how do we know what the probability is that any given atom or set of atoms will radiate a certain wavelength at a certain intensity? It seems that without further assumptions on this, we cannot proceed, and yet as evidenced by the black hole example alluded to above, this law is very universal.

The furthest I got with this was to say that at a time $\Delta t$ later, that's presumably at least longer than the vibration time for the atoms at the given temperature, we can say the probability is still given by the above, only that now it will have a different energy, $E'$, and temperature $T' := T - \Delta T$. Namely,

$$f_{E'}(E') := \frac{1}{Z'} e^{-E'/(k_B T')}$$

with the new partition function for $Z'$. Note that in each case integration shows $Z = k_B T$ so we can simplify both to

$$f_E(E) = \frac{1}{k_B T} e^{-E/(k_B T)}$$
$$f_{E'}(E') = \frac{1}{k_B T'} e^{-E'/(k_B T')}$$

Though then we get that $E'$ can be larger than $E$ if we already measured $E$ - however that's not necessarily wrong because the atom could still have gained from its surrounding atoms. In particular, the energy difference $\Delta E := E' - E$ satisfies the equation

$$\Delta E = E_\text{gain from surrounding atoms} - E_\text{loss from surrounding atoms} + E_\text{gain from EM field} - E_\text{loss to EM field}$$

We can of course assume that $E_\text{gain from EM field} = 0$ if we presume the object initially radiates into vacuum, which would be one of the important starting assumptions. However, we then run into two more things:

1. What proportion of $\Delta E$ is accounted for by $E_\text{loss to EM field}$? It seems we must involve electromagnetic theory into here because Planck's law involves $c$, the speed of light, but I'm not sure how yet without getting overly specific about the details of an atom.
2. Even if we can find that, how do we get what *wavelengths* that light comes out from? Even though we want to take $\Delta E$ small, ideally to find a limiting behavior, during that we can find any number of compatible wavelengths that might be possible for emission to occur at, even using a photonic model for light (which is needed to get Planck's law). Namely we have
   $$E_\text{loss to EM field} = nh\nu$$
   for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, while *both* $n$ and $\nu$ are *free* variables.

So what can we do? Is this even a valid approach to this problem at all, or am I completely off base?

Comment: Just wondering, can't we use the fact that energy of a SHO for adiabatic system is proportional to frequency (in classical setting)? Then classically, any  oscillation of charges will produce EM fields. If we write the Hamiltonian of the system (similar to harmonic oscillator) assuming adiabatic approximation, we might get something similar to Planck's law

Comment: @KP99 I thought of that, but a SHO has 1 natural frequency. We need to get a continuum of frequencies out. Perhaps we can relate that somehow to the energy - basically we should consider there to be an energy-frequency relation (perhaps maybe also a density-of-states for each frequency too) and for a perfect black body this should have certain characteristics. Maybe the way to do it is to consider a solid crystal and use the vibratory modes thereof.

Comment: We can't get Planck distribution from one electron oscillator. Atleast we can get a quasi continuous distribution if we assume a solid crystal as you have mentioned, and then approximate Hamiltonian of each electron to that of harmonic oscillator. $E\sim \nu$  for each harmonic oscillator can be obtained from adiabatic assumption